# Loopback query documents based on related model count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a Category collection that has a hasMany relation with an Article collection. I want to query categories and sort/order the result based on the related model(article) count.

example:

category 'A' has 5 articles

category 'B' has 6 articles

category 'C' has 3 articles

I want my result sorted [B, A, C].

I am using loopback v3 and mongodb as my database.

```
// My current code, querying published categories

Category.find({where : {isPublished : true}, order: 'something DESC'},function(error, result){
     console.log(result);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Would there be any issue if you just sort the articles collection and in the filter include the related categories collection

Comment: But how would it solve my problem. I can retrieve all categories and include the articles model then apply .length() on the articles to know which category has the most articles but that would be too heavy, especially if my database is medium to large scale.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't achieve that without a bit of code.

First method would be to sort the result in a remote function or remote hook, as Nader suggests.

The second method would be the add a field `articlesCount` in your `Category` model, then update this value each an `article` is added or removed in a remote hook. Then you can filter and sort `Category` instances directly on this property.